# Rename [austin-power] to [austin-powers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Please rename [austin-power](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austin-power) to [austin-powers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austin-powers).

Comment: Why not just rename the tag?

Comment: That's what this post is trying to do? SE told me to open a meta post when I tried to do it myself.

Comment: Can't able to do that. Sorry for missing s while creating the tag. Now its not allowing me to change it by saying **You are attempting to create the tag [austin-powers]; however the tag [austin-power] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.**

Comment: @AnkitSharma No worries. I'm sure that a mod will be able to take care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Done